# How can I specify the name of pdf print for react native project for iOS

Tags: react-native, pdf

I'm using both `expo-print` and `expo-sharing` to save file.

```
const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({html});
await shareAsync(uri, { UTI: ".pdf", mimeType: "application/pdf" });
```

by default it is using UUID, I want to specify the file eg, `abc.pdf`, but I don't see the doc has any option to setup the file name.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer [here](https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-print-creating-pdf-and-giving-it-a-file-name/36164/3)

```
import * as Print from 'expo-print'
```

import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'

```
const printToPdf = async () => {
    const response = await Print.printToFileAsync({
        html: createHtmlStringForPdf(),
    })

    // this changes the bit after the last slash of the uri (the document's name) to "invoice_<date of transaction"

    const pdfName = `${response.uri.slice(
        0,
        response.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1
    )}invoice_${readableDate.getTime()}.pdf`

    await FileSystem.moveAsync({
        from: response.uri,
        to: pdfName,
    })
    sharePdf(pdfName)
}

const sharePdf = (url) => {
    Sharing.shareAsync(url)
}
```